# File uploading using Flash and php ini limitation

Tags: flash, upload, limit, php

I have recently subscribed to a new hosting which only allows 2mb upload for php. I was wondering can I use Flash uploader like [SWFupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) to upload more than 2mb files ? 
Thanks

Comment: `php_value memory_limit 300M` and 
`php_value post_max_size 300M`and 
`php_value upload_max_filesize 300M` and in htaccess

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting, can I change the limit too ?

Comment: yes defiantly .. i think you have access to the .htaccess file  you can write this in that file

Comment: check 3ed methoed in link  http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
void setFileSizeLimit(file_size_limit)
```

Dynamically modifies the file_size_limit setting. This applies to all future files that are queued. The file_size_limit parameter will accept a unit. Valid units are B, KB, MB, and GB. The default unit is KB.

Examples: 2147483648 B, 2097152, 2097152KB, 2048 MB, 2 GB

**Useful read**

[**SWFUpload   Documentation**](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/)

Comment: thanks. By the way, can I use the same method of queuing for jQuery uploader like this one http://fineuploader.com/index.html ?

Comment: the method in answer is for the only swfuploader but you can use the comment to increase the upload limit for any uploader